# Trying to add Arch Linux to a UEFI hard drive with Ubuntu, Debian, and GRUB already installed

Tags: grub, uefi, arch-linux

I downloaded Arch 64 bit ISO to a USB thumb drive and booted into it.  The target system is a Gigabyte board with an Athlon CPU and 8GB RAM, 1 TB hard drive with UEFI.

Followed the built-in "Installation_Guide" script and followed it as closely as possible.  Some of it is a little vague.

I've also reviewed this article, but neither it or the Installation Guide really get into what to do if you're trying to multi-boot.  https://www.tecmint.com/arch-linux-installation-and-configuration-guide/

Since I already have the first partition sda1 being used as the "boot partition" (I guess) and Ubuntu is on sda2, Debian on sda3, and swap on sda4, I created sda5 with fdisk and formatted it as ext4.  Installed Arch and vi following the instructions.  Used the existing swap partition, why not?  Only one OS can run at a time.

Went through all the language and locale and time zone configuration.  Set up localhost and hostname.

I created the fstab and it has 3 entries, one for the EFI partition, one for swap, and another for the main OS.  Installed GRUB under the chroot environment.

Anyway, after I reboot, I am just looking at the same boot selections I had before... Ubuntu (several options) and Debian.  I booted again from the Arch USB and was able to get over to sda5 and confirm that everything's still there.

I feel like I'm just missing ONE IMPORTANT STEP but I can't figure out what it is.  Thanks for any guidance.

This related article from 5 years ago suggests the use of grub-probe (I didn't try that yet).  It also indicates that grub has lots of documentation.  Why yes it does.  Lots and lots.  Maybe even too much.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139756/how-to-triple-boot-debian-arch-linux-ubuntu

Logging into Ubuntu, looking at /proc/partitions.  Only results from /dev/sda are shown.

```
larry@Old-Gigabyte:~$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1     524288 sda1
   8        2  167912448 sda2
   8        3  163086336 sda3
   8        4   16384000 sda4
   8        5   52428800 sda5
larry@Old-Gigabyte:~$
```

fdisk /dev/sda shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 680F4B2C-CEB6-4011-A765-471C99ED79AF

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 336875519 335824896 160.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  336875520 663048191 326172672 155.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  663048192 695816191  32768000  15.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda5  695816192 800673791 104857600    50G Linux filesystem
```

/etc/fstab is:

```
    larry@Old-Gigabyte:~$ cat /mnt/arch/etc/fstab 
# /dev/sda5
UUID=ea07243f-d202-4061-bd97-aa166676e0de   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/sda1
UUID=21A8-3956          /efi        vfat        rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/sda4
UUID=35a1d790-7070-4056-8536-799099738d6b   none        swap        defaults    0 0

larry@Old-Gigabyte:~$
```

Some info from the efi partition:

```
root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi/EFI/ubuntu# cd ../..
root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi# ls -lR
.:
total 4
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Sep  5  2019 EFI

./EFI:
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep  5  2019 BOOT
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Mar  5  2020 ubuntu

./EFI/BOOT:
total 3748
-rwx------ 1 root root 1341560 Mar 18 20:24 BOOTX64.EFI
-rwx------ 1 root root 1222800 Mar 18 20:24 fbx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1269496 Sep  5  2019 mmx64.efi

./EFI/ubuntu:
total 3672
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 Mar 18 20:24 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwx------ 1 root root     126 Mar 18 20:24 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 1130368 Mar 18 20:24 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1277024 Mar 18 20:24 mmx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1341560 Mar 18 20:24 shimx64.efi
root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi# 

root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi# cat EFI/ubuntu/BOOTX64.CSV 
shimx64.efi,ubuntu,,This is the boot entry for ubuntu
root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi# 

root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi# cat EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
search.fs_uuid 0fb648e7-69b8-4701-be8f-3a01a1c820da root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
root@Old-Gigabyte:/mnt/efi#
```

I am onto something here as the actual GRUB menu entries appear to be on the Ubuntu partition (it's what I installed first).  The contents of this file appear to be generated, and at the top I see:

```
root@Old-Gigabyte:/boot/grub# cat grub.cfg
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

I'm going to look at grub-mkconfig....

OK, what's interesting is that the grub.cfg on the Ubuntu partition appears to be the correct one.  I guess there's some sort of daisy-chain going on?

I ran this to update the /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
root@Old-Gigabyte:/boot/grub# grub-mkconfig -o ./grub.cfg
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-71-generic
Found Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on /dev/sda3
Found Arch Linux on /dev/sda5
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
root@Old-Gigabyte:/boot/grub#
```

Rebooting now, hoping for the best.

Thanks for any clues.

DL

Comment: You need to understand (1) which Grub is actually booting (UEFI boot) and that you may keep it and (2) whether #1 is Debian or Ubuntu just boot that one and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  As of now, I updated the grub.cfg in the Ubuntu partition and now I am able to boot into Ubuntu, Debian, or Arch.  It's possible that if I updated the grub.cfg in the efi partition it would also work but I'm not one to fix it when it's working.